# Why would IncomingMessage stream not pipe in a docker container running on Linux?

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, express

I am making a request to a node service running inside a docker container with a linux OS.

The following code works perfectly when I run it locally on windows without docker, but in a linux docker container it seems to do nothing with the stream, and then eventually aborts. The logs further down show what is happening in the code.

I first thought that it might be a disk space issue in the container, but after reading up about it, it doesn't seem necessary to manage the disk space at all.

So what could be the issue? Or how could I debug this problem further?

> EDIT: I have now tried the following: 1. confirmed that there is 25GB free disk space, 2. Changed the file name to a valid relative path for the OS, 3. Changed the filename from a GUID to something simpler and smaller like 'dummy.tmp', 4. Also made sure I subscribe to the 'finish' event before piping the stream.

The code:

```
module.exports = function useTempFile(req, fileName, handlerAsync) {

    const logDebug = (message) => logger.debug('useTempFile', message);
    const logError = (message) => logger.error('useTempFile', message);

    logDebug('invoked');

    checkDiskSpace(path.join(process.cwd(), srcDirectoryName)).then(diskSpace => {
        logDebug(`disk space: ${JSON.stringify(diskSpace)}`);
    }).catch(error => {
        logError(`disk space error: ${error}`);
    });

    let resolve = null;
    let reject = null;

    const promise = new Promise((innerResolve, innerReject) => {
        resolve = innerResolve;
        reject = innerReject;
    });

    const tempFileName = path.join(process.cwd(), srcDirectoryName, `${fileName || uuid.v4()}.tmp`);
    try {
        logDebug(`creating Write Stream, cwd: ${process.cwd()}, temp file name: ${tempFileName}`);
        const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(tempFileName);
        fileStream.on('file', () => logDebug('\'file\' event'));
        fileStream.on('finish', async () => {
            logDebug('\'finish\' event');
            try {
                /* first validate that we actually received a file stream that was not empty */
                const stats = await util.promisify(fs.stat)(tempFileName);
                if (stats.size === 0)
                    reject(new ValidationError('File or stream is empty. Invalid request.'));
                else {
                    if (!(await fsExistsAsync(tempFileName)))
                        throw new ValidationError('Temp file is no longer available');
                    const tempFile = fs.createReadStream(tempFileName);
                    const result = await handlerAsync(tempFile);

                    resolve(result);
                }
            } catch (e) {
                logError(`'finish' event error: ${e.stack || e}`);
                reject(e);
                throw e;
            } finally {
                await _deleteAsync(tempFileName);
            }
        });
        fileStream.on('error', async (err) => {
            logError(`'error' event: ${err.stack || err}`);
            await _deleteAsync(tempFileName);
            reject(err);
        });
        fileStream.on('close', () => logDebug('\'close\' event'));

        logDebug(`piping to Write stream: writable: ${fileStream.writable}, writableEnded: ${fileStream.writableEnded}, writableFinished: ${fileStream.writableFinished}`);
        if (req.stream) {
            logDebug(`Received a full stream object, aborted: ${req.stream.aborted}, complete: ${req.stream.complete}, readable: ${req.stream.readable}`);
            req.stream.pipe(fileStream);
            req.stream.on('aborted', () => logDebug('incoming stream \'aborted\' event'));
            req.stream.on('close', () => logDebug('incoming stream \'close\' event'));
        } else {
            logDebug('Didn\'t receive a full stream object');
            req.pipe(fileStream);
        }
        logDebug('waiting for stream write and pipe operation');
    } catch (e) {
        logError((e.stack || e));
        reject(e);
        throw e;
    } 

    return promise;
};
```

The log output:

```
2019-09-11T11:54:13.421Z [DEBUG] deployService - authorized 
2019-09-11T11:54:13.421Z [DEBUG] startPackageSession - invoked 
2019-09-11T11:54:13.422Z [DEBUG] useTempFile - invoked 
2019-09-11T11:54:13.430Z [DEBUG] useTempFile - creating Write Stream, cwd: /apps, temp file name: /apps/service/dummyservice.tmp

2019-09-11T11:54:13.430Z [DEBUG] useTempFile - Received a full stream object, aborted: false, complete: false, readable: true 
2019-09-11T11:54:13.430Z [DEBUG] useTempFile - piping to Write stream: writable: true, writableEnded: undefined, writableFinished: undefined 
2019-09-11T11:54:13.430Z [DEBUG] useTempFile - waiting for stream write and pipe operation 
2019-09-11T11:54:13.432Z [DEBUG] useTempFile - disk space: {"diskPath":"/","free":24688365568,"size":107317563392} 
2019-09-11T11:55:00.086Z [DEBUG] useTempFile - incoming stream 'aborted' event 
2019-09-11T11:55:00.087Z [DEBUG] useTempFile - incoming stream 'close' event
```

The dockerfile:

```
FROM dockereelb.int.capinet:8443/nodeplatform/platform_node:1.0.2_signed
WORKDIR /apps/service
COPY . .
WORKDIR /apps 
ENTRYPOINT ["/apps/runtime/node/bin/node", "--max-http-header-size=80000", "/apps/platform/main.js", "/apps/service"]
```

Comment: Hi Martin, can you edit your answer and post your Dockerfile?

Comment: Hello @RobertoGonçalves, I added the dockerfile.